# Integration $ I=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{c-1} \ln(1+x) dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to handle the integration that's given below.

$$ I=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{c-1} \ln(1+x) dx   $$
where $c$ and $x$ are both positive numbers. I found a conditional solution for the above integration from the 'table of integrals' book by Gradshteyn as:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\mu-1} \ln(1+\gamma x) dx= \frac{\pi}{\mu \gamma^{u}\sin \mu\pi} $$ 
with the condition $\left [-1<\Re \mu <0, |\arg \gamma|<\pi \right]$. My expression does not satisfy the conditions of the above given solution.

Any hint/help will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $c>0$ your integral diverges, as $I\ge\int_1^\infty x^{-1}\ln xdx=[\tfrac{1}{2}\ln^2x]_1^\infty=\infty$.